# Java RegEx to match substring delimited by variable number of asterisks when the asterisk is not at beginning or end of line

Tags: java, regex

I'm stuck on something I must be missing on a strange regex with a negative/positive look behind that should work extracting substrings delimiters made by at least 2 contiguous asterisks, with the caveat that the 2 or more asterisks should not be neither at the start nor at the end of the line of text.

Let me make an example. From something like this:

```
*** DRIVER FEE -10.00/DAY - SPOUSE ALSO CHARGED ****QUALIFICATIONS FOR RENTERS FROM NON US COUNTRIES*** -MUST HAVE A *** VALID DRIVERS LICENSE***
```

I should capture only the asterisks series in the middle, so those before QUALIFICATIONS, those following COUNTRIES and those before VALID

I should not capture asterisks before DRIVER and after LICENSE, using the example above.

I could sort out:

\b([**]+)\B

and

\B([**]+)\b

but these don't work to exclude those at the beginning and end of text.

Any idea on how to make the capture?

Comment: Try `(?<=[^*])\*+(?=[^*])`, see https://regex101.com/r/kXO4A9/1

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I must check that I have at least 2 asterisks otherwise they should not be captured that is why I was doing [**]. Do you know hot to specify the number of min asterisks required to trigger the capture ?

Comment: Yes, you need a limiting quantifier like `{2,}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=[^*])\*{2,}(?=[^*])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kXO4A9/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<=[^*])` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `*` char immediately on the left
- `\*{2,}` - two or more asterisk chars
- `(?=[^*])` - a positive lookahead that requires a `*` char immediately on the right.